# Bug in rendering math in comments

Tags: bug, mathjax, comment

I recently left a comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/752559/8173) containing the equation
$$\sigma(i_1\;i_2\;\cdots\;i_n)\sigma^{-1}=(\sigma(i_1)\;\sigma(i_2)\;\cdots\;\sigma(i_n))$$
but the last $\sigma$ is broken, displaying instead as ${\color{red}\s}\;igma$. There is no space or invisible character seperating the s from igma.

The un-rendered of the comment:

> \$\$\sigma(i_1\;i_2\;\cdots\;i_n)\sigma^{-1}=(\sigma(i_1)\;\sigma(i_2)\;\cdots\;\sigma(i_n))\$\$

It seems that if I add spaces around the equals sign, the comment renders correctly. Perhaps there is some length restriction on the parser that handles comments?

Comment: Illustration: $$\sigma(i_1\;i_2\;\cdots\;i_n)\sigma^{-1}=(\sigma(i_1)\;\sigma(i_2)\;\cdots\;\sigma(i_n))$$

Comment: Adding spaces around equals sign: $$\sigma(i_1\;i_2\;\cdots\;i_n)\sigma^{-1} = (\sigma(i_1)\;\sigma(i_2)\;\cdots\;\sigma(i_n))$$

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Found it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [*StackExchange™ WhiteSpace EnforcementOfficer™*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91512/251274) at work. Looking at the HTML source of the page, you'll see `\s&zwnj;&#8203;igma` there:

```
@abe15 The key is to know that $$\sigma(i_1\;i_2\;\cdots\;i_n)\sigma^{-1}=(\sigma(i_1)\;\sigma(i_2)\;\cdots\;\s&zwnj;&#8203;igma(i_n))$$
```

Inserting a space in LaTeX markup eliminates the (perceived) need for inserting `&zwnj;&#8203;`.

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely the culprit. I wonder if there is a way to force breaks and not break mathjax?

Comment: @AlexBecker The most logical way is probably to configure MathJax on SE to perform pre-parsing string replacement such as `&zwnj;&#8203;` $\to$ empty string (and `&amp;` $\to$ `&`, to fix [another issue](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/13319/)). If this is done via parameters in the MathJax configuration script, the effect would be neatly localized to SE. I don't think introducing support for such parameters would be too much  work for MathJax team, considering that SE is one of [five Partners](http://www.mathjax.org/sponsors/#partners), with annual support level of $20,000.